# How do I update docker images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I read that docker works with layers, so when creating a `container` with a `Dockerfile`, you start with the base image, then subsequent commands run add a layer to the container, so if you save the state of that new container, you have a new image. There are a couple of things I'm wondering about this.

If I start from a `Ubuntu` image, which is pretty big and bulky since its a complete OS, then I add a few tools to it and save this as a new image which I upload to the hub. If someone downloads my image, and they already have a Ubuntu image saved in their `images folder`, does this mean they can skip downloading `Ubuntu` since they already have the image? If so, how does this work when I modify parts of the original image, does Docker use its cached data to selectively apply those changes to the `Ubuntu image` after it loads it?

2.) How do I update an image that I built by modifying the Dockerfile? I setup a simple django project with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ENV APPLICATION_ROOT /app
ENV APP_ENVIRONMENT L

RUN mkdir -p $APPLICATION_ROOT
WORKDIR $APPLICATION_ROOT
ADD requirements.txt $APPLICATION_ROOT
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . $APPLICATION_ROOT
```

and used this to create the image in the beginning. So everytime I create a box, it loads all these `environment variables`, if I rebuild the box completely it reinstalls the packages and all the extras. I need to add a new environment variable, so I added it to the bottom of the `Dockerfile`, along with a test variable:

```
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS 1
ENV TEST_ENV_VAR TEST
```

When I delete the container and the image, and build a new container, it all seems to go accordingly, it tells me that it creates the new Step 4 : ENV

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS 1
 ---> Running in 75551ea311b2
 ---> b25b60e29f18
Removing intermediate container 75551ea311b2
```

So its like something gets lost in some of these intermediate container transitions. Is this how the caching system works, every new layer is an `intermediate container`? So with that in mind, how do you add a new layer, do you always have to add the new data at the bottom of the Dockerfile? Or would it be better to leave the Dockerfile alone once the image is built, and just modify the `container` and built a new image?

**EDIT** I just tried installing an image, a package called  `bwawrik/bioinformatics`, which is a CentOS based container which has a wide range of tools installed.

It froze half way through, so I exited it and then ran it again to see if everything was installed:

```
$ docker pull bwawrik/bioinformatics
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from bwawrik/bioinformatics

a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
7e78dbe53fdd: Already exists
ebcc98113eaa: Already exists
598d3c8fd678: Already exists
12520d1e1960: Already exists
9b4912d2bc7b: Already exists
c64f941884ae: Already exists
24371a4298bf: Already exists
993de48846f3: Already exists
2231b3c00b9e: Already exists
2d67c793630d: Already exists
d43673e70e8e: Already exists
fe4f50dda611: Already exists
33300f752b24: Already exists
b4eec31201d8: Already exists
f34092f697e8: Already exists
e49521d8fb4f: Already exists
8349c93680fe: Already exists
929d44a7a5a1: Already exists
09a30957f0fb: Already exists
4611e742e0b5: Already exists
25aacf0148db: Already exists
74da82504b6c: Already exists
3e0aac083b86: Already exists
f52c7e0ac000: Already exists
35eee92aaf2f: Already exists
5f6d8eb70885: Already exists
536920bfe266: Already exists
98638e678c51: Already exists
9123956b991d: Already exists
1c4c8a29cd65: Already exists
1804bf352a97: Already exists
aa6fe9359956: Already exists
e7e38d1250a9: Already exists
05e935c831dc: Already exists
b7dfc22c26f3: Already exists
1514d4797ffd: Already exists
Digest: sha256:0391808e21b7b5cc0eb44fc2dad0d7f5415115bdaafb4534c0b6a12efd47a88b
Status: Image is up to date for bwawrik/bioinformatics:latest
```

So it definitely installed the package in pieces, not all in one go. Are these pieces, different images?

Comment: In case you landed on this question thinking that "update" means "get the latest version": `docker pull <image>`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### image vs. container

First, let me clarify some terminology.

**image**: A static, immutable object. This is the thing you build when you run `docker build` using a `Dockerfile`. An image is not a thing that runs.

Images are composed of layers. an image might have only one layer, or it might have many layers.

**container**: A running thing. It uses an image as its starting template.

This is similar to a binary program and a process. You have a binary program on disk (such as `/bin/sh`), and when you run it, it is a process on your system. This is similar to the relationship between images and containers.

### Adding layers to a base image

You can build your own image from a base image (such as `ubuntu` in your example). Some commands in your `Dockerfile` will create a new layer in the ultimate image. Some of those are `RUN`, `COPY`, and `ADD`.

The very first layer has no parent layer. But every other layer will have a parent layer. In this way they link to one another, stacking up like pancakes.

Each layer has a unique ID (the long hexadecimal hashes you have already seen). They can also have human-friendly names, known as *tags* (e.g. `ubuntu:16.04`).

### What is a layer vs. an image?

Technically, each layer is also an image. If you build a new image and it has 5 layers, you can use that image and it will contain all 5 layers. If you run a container using the third layer in the stack as your image ID, you can do that too - but it would only contain 3 layers. The one you specify and the two that are its ancestors.

But as a matter of convention, the term "image" generally means the layer that has a tag associated. When you run `docker images`, it will show you all of the top-level images, and hide the layers beneath (but you can show them all with `-a`).

### What is an intermediate container?

When `docker build` runs, it does all of its work inside of containers (naturally!) So if it encounters a `RUN` step, it will create a container from the current top layer, run the specified commands in there, and then save the result as a new layer. Then it will create a container from this new layer, run the next thing... etc.

The intermediate containers are only used for the build process, and are discarded after the build.

### How layer filesystems work

You asked whether someone downloading your `ubuntu`-based image are only doing a partial download, if they already had the `ubuntu` image locally.

Yes! That's exactly right.

Every layer uses the layer beneath it as a base. The new layer is basically a diff between that layer and a new state. It's not a diff in the same way as a git commit might work, though. It works at the file level, not at a the line level.

Say you started from `ubuntu`, and you ran this Dockerfile.

```
FROM: ubuntu:16.04
RUN groupadd dan && useradd -g dan dan
```

This would result in a two layer image. The first layer would be the `ubuntu` image. The second would probably have only a handful of changes.

- A newer copy of `/etc/passwd` with user "dan"
- A newer copy of `/etc/group` with group "dan"
- A new directory `/home/dan`
- A couple of default files like `/home/dan/.bashrc`

And that's it. If you start a container from this image, those few files would be in the topmost layer, and everything else would come from the filesystem in the `ubuntu` image.

### The top-most read-write layer in a container

One other point. When you run a container, you can write files in the filesystem. But if you stop the container and run another container from the same image, everything is reset. So where are the files written?

Images are immutable, so once they are created, they can't be changed. You can build a new version, but that's a new image. It would have a different ID and would not be the same image.

A container has a top-level read-write layer which is put on top of the image layers. Any writes happen in that layer. It works just like the other layers. If you need to modify a file (or add one, or delete one), that is done in the top layer, and doesn't affect the lower layers. If the file exists already, it is copied into the read-write layer, and then modified. This is known as copy-on-write (CoW).

### Where to add changes

Do you have to add new things to the bottom of Dockerfile? No, you can add anything anywhere (or change anything).

However, how you do things does affect your build times because of how the build caching works.

Docker will try to cache results during builds. If it finds as it reads through Dockerfile that the `FROM` is the same, the first `RUN` is the same, the second `RUN` is the same... it will assume it has already done those steps, and will use cached results. If it encounters something that is different from the last build, it will invalidate the cache. Everything from that point on will be re-run fresh.

Some things will always invalidate the cache. For instance if you use `ADD` or `COPY`, those always invalidate the cache. That's because Docker only keeps track of what the build commands are. It doesn't try to figure out "is this version of the file I'm copying the same one as last time?"

So it is a common practice to start with `FROM`, then put very static things like `RUN` commands that install packages with e.g. `apt-get`, etc. Those things tend to not change a lot after your Dockerfile has been initially written. Later in the file is a more convenient place to put things that change more often.

It's hard to concisely give good advice on this, because it really depends on the project in question. But it pays to learn how the build caching works and try to take advantage of it.

Comment: Excellent clarifications for beginners(like me). Can you also add information about any other important aspects eg docker server, linux chroot jail?

Comment: Does --no-cache invalidate and pull the base image if it was remotely updated?